# high order DE :$y''''+y'''=1-x^2\,e^{-x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing some exercise and I got to this question:
SOLVE:  $ y''''+y'''=1-x^2e^{-x}$,
the associated homegeneous eqation  solution is simple to calculate
that is,
$y_h=c_1+c_2x+c_3x^2+c_4e^{-x}$
However, when it comes to particular solution ,it is really trivial and hard.
can anyone teach me how to solve the problem in the easiet way?that is ,solve the problem as quick as possible

Comment: Have you tried making a substitution of the form $w=y'''$, $w'=y''''$ and then solving in terms of $w$? This was something my teacher once mentioned could be done. Or at least something similar to this. I believe he referred to the technique as making a "system of equations."

Comment: @user113644 The suggestion by graydad is exactly what you need here. Any time the ODE is missing the low order derivatives (orders 0,  1, 2 here), take the lowest present derivative as a new unknown.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure how to solve it the quickest.  To give some idea on the particular solution, though, start by multiplying both sides by $e^x$.

$$e^xy''''+e^xy'''=(e^xy''')'=e^x-x^2$$
$$e^xy'''=e^x-\frac{x^3}3+k$$
$$y'''=1-\frac{x^3}3e^{-x}+ke^{-x}$$

Integrating both sides $3$ times will yield a complete solution.  The first term will integrate easily to $\frac{x^3}6$.  The next term is the tricky one, but it should be in the form $ax^3e^{-x}+bx^2e^{-x}+cxe^{-x}$.   An $e^{-x}$ term is not included since that's part of the homogeneous solution.